# Can't add event when iterate a NodeList using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, foreach, addeventlistener

I'm trying to iterate a NodeList  object using javascript, and i want to a click event to eatch item :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
try {

    posts.map(post => {
        container.innerHTML += outPutHtml(post); // user-interaction elements are created with ajax request 
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
   
} finally {
    highlight.highlightAll();
```

});

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".user-interaction");

console.log(elements); //   NodeList []length: 0[[Prototype]]: NodeList
console.log(typeof elements); // object

elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log('ok');
    });
});
```

The click event on element doesn't work !

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Your list is empty (length: 0) which means no elements with className `.user-interaction` were found at the time the script has been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const addListeners = () => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".user-interaction");

  console.log(elements); //   NodeList []length: 0[[Prototype]]: NodeList
  console.log(typeof elements); // object

  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log('ok');
    });
  });
};

async function makeAjaxrequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  })
}




const runTheApp = async() => {
  console.log('start')
  await makeAjaxrequest();
  console.log('done')
  addListeners();
}


runTheApp();
```

```css
.user-interaction {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="user-interaction">1</div>
<div class="user-interaction">2</div>
<div class="user-interaction">3</div>
```

wrap your logic in

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
   console.log('your logic here')
});
```

Comment: I updated my question,  the user-interaction elements are getting by an async ajax request,  how can i add a clik event ?

Comment: it works when  i put the code in the finally block